# How to display Google Maps directions result on page

Tags: google-maps

I want to have customers be able to enter their address into a text box, press submit, and then display the results on my own page instead of it going directly to maps.google.com.  I am not familiar with the Google Maps API, so I was wondering how I could go about doing this?

I know how to have customers enter their address and get directions (via this link: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/get-directions-form-google-maps/) but now I just need to know how to take those results and embed them into a page on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this page to get started (an API key is optional)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Then, you need a text field and a button, to convert (geocode) an address like 123 Main St. to latitude and longitude coordinates. You may have to validate and create fields like town and state because the geocoder might send the marker to the wrong place.

Read this page for the details, I think the example is enough:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Comment: You might also want to take a look at the directions documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions